# Openerp 7 many2one dropdown should display field of related record

Tags: odoo

If you install Openerp 7 with recruitment module. And create a simple entry with following values e.g.

**Subject** (internal field `name = 'name'`) = 10 Year Experience

**Applicant Name** = Jhon Smith

Then if you create a custom module with following columns

```
_columns = {
   'applicant_id': fields.many2one('hr.applicant', 'Applicant', required=True),
}
```

The view widget by default will show a drop-down with the Subject (internal field name ='name') field but i want to show applicant name (internal field `name='partner_name'`) field in drop down, when creating a new record in my custom module.

In Summary how can I display Applicant's Name instead of Subject in drop-down widget in my custom module.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `applicant_id` in `_rec_name` in your custom module.

Try this:

```
_rec_name = 'applicant_id'
```

Have a look at [Predefined fields.](https://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/object_attributes.html/#predefined-fields)

Answer (score 0):

In openerp there is a function called `name_get()`.This function returns a list of tuples containing ID of the record and name tobe displayed. So override this function and return list of tuples containing ID of the record and applicant name